# How to resolve Invisible class error in Randoop?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, automated-tests, randoop

I have a simple class in java conatining something like this

```
package math;

public class Math {
    /*Expected Behavior:
          Given upperBound >= 0, the method returns
               1 + 2 + ... + upperBound                 
      But This method is buggy and works only on
      inputs with odd value, e.g. for upperBound == 4,
      the method returns 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 1 instead of
      1 + 2 + 3 + 4                                   */
    public static int sum(int upperBound) {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= upperBound; i++) {
            s += i;
        }
        if (upperBound % 2 == 0) {// <--------- BUG!
            s++;                  // <--------- BUG!
        }                         // <--------- BUG!
        return s;
    }
}
```

now for this I am trying to generate unit test case using randoop and the command which I am using here is given below and my Math.class file is in /home/niteshb/Downloads/randoop-4.2.6/Tests.class

```
java -cp /home/niteshb/Downloads/randoop-4.2.6:/home/niteshb/Downloads/randoop-4.2.6/randoop-all-4.2.6.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=Math --literals-file=CLASSES
```

here after execution I am getting error as

```
Cannot instantiate non-visible Math specified via --testclass or --classlist.

Will try to generate tests for 0 out of 1 classes.
You provided no methods to test, so no tests for them can be generated.

Additional diagnostis appear below.
Model with hashcode 1253946629:
  classTypes = [java.lang.Object]
  inputTypes = []
  coveredClassesGoal = []
  classLiteralMap = {}
  annotatedTestValues = []
  contracts = ContractSet[size=12]
    arity 1: [randoop.contract.EqualsReflexive@7ce6a65d, randoop.contract.EqualsToNullRetFalse@1500955a, randoop.contract.EqualsReturnsNormally@e874448, randoop.contract.CompareToReflexive@29b5cd00, randoop.contract.SizeToArrayLength@60285225]
    arity 2: [randoop.contract.EqualsSymmetric@7113b13f, randoop.contract.EqualsHashcode@45820e51, randoop.contract.CompareToAntiSymmetric@42d8062c, randoop.contract.CompareToEquals@6043cd28]
    arity 3: [randoop.contract.EqualsTransitive@cb51256, randoop.contract.CompareToSubs@59906517, randoop.contract.CompareToTransitive@5bfbf16f]
  omitMethods = [
    \bensuresCapacity\b
    ^\Qcom.google.common.collect.Iterators.cycle(
    ^\Qorg.apache.commons.math4.genetics.GeneticAlgorithm.getRandomGenerator()\E$
    ^\Qorg.apache.commons.math4.util.FastMath.random()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Date.<init>()\E$
    ^\Qorg.joda.time.DateTime.now()\E$
    ^\Qorg.joda.time.LocalDate.<init>\E$
    ^\Qnew org.joda.time.Partial.<init>()\E$
    ^\Qjava.io.File.list()\E$
    ^\Qjava.io.File.list(java.io.FilenameFilter)\E$
    ^\Qjava.io.File.listFiles()\E$
    ^\Qjava.io.File.listFiles(java.io.FileFilter)\E$
    ^\Qjava.io.File.listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)\E$
    ^\Qjava.io.File.listRoots()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.Class.getSigners()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.Object.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.String.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.clearProperty(java.lang.String)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.console()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.getProperties()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.getSecurityManager()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.getenv()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.getenv(java.lang.String)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.inheritedChannel()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.mapLibraryName(java.lang.String)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.nanoTime()\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.System.setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)\E$
    ^\Qjava.lang.reflect.Method.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.text.BreakIterator.getAvailableLocales()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.AbstractList.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.AbstractSet.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.deepHashCode(java.lang.Object[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(boolean[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(byte[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(char[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(double[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(float[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(int[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(java.lang.Object[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(long[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Arrays.hashCode(short[])\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Collection.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Collections.shuffle(java.util.List)\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Comparator.compare(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.List.hashCode()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Random.<init>()\E$
    ^\Qjava.util.Set.hashCode()\E$
  ]
Operations: (1)
  java.lang.Object.<init> : () -> java.lang.Object

There are no methods for Randoop to test.  See diagnostics above.  Exiting.
```

can someone pls help me with this , I am stucked here for long time tried different things but didnt worked out ..

Comment: Your question shows a class named `math.Math`, but then it mentions a class `Welcomes` and that is what is shown in the Randoop output.  You seem to have mixed up two different runs of Randoop.  Can you fix this in your question?  Also, if the class you are trying to run is `Welcomes`, is this a duplicate of https://github.com/randoop/randoop/issues/917 ?

Comment: oh by mistake I mixed up , its fixed now @mernst ,just have a small query I have a very complex code containing dependency on many classes , can randoop go through it , I tried in one but literally failed , am I doing something wrong or there is some limitation of randoop

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this it worked

```
java -classpath /home/niteshb/Downloads/randoop-4.2.6:/home/niteshb/Downloads/randoop-4.2.6/randoop-all-4.2.6.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=math.Math --output-limit=10
```